# How to build a simple blog where content could be published securely to user groups?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am developing a PHP application and want to host a blog to communicate with my alpha, beta, and (hopefully) other users.  I have some experience with Drupal, so am planning to put it to use.

I installed Acquia Commons.  It was impressive, perhaps too impressive for my needs.  I started out by trying to remove some of the features, and I found that there's not much documentation freely available for it.  (I don't want a paid service - this startup has not made any money).

I am thinking that Drupal Core with [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) added might be sufficient, but I'm not sure since I have not used Organic Groups before.  And of course, there could be other distributions or modules that I don't know about too.

So, the question is, if your Drupal skills were pretty basic, how would you go about building a simple blog where content could be published securely to user groups?

EDIT: Maybe my usage of the word 'groups' is confusing the issue.  Perhaps I could do this simply by creating different roles, such as Alpha User, Beta User, and assigning users to those roles.  In that case, how would I go about restricting access to content based on role?

Comment: Personally, if I were developing a PHP application, I would want to spend my time developing that, not messing around with blog configuration.  Setting up Organic Groups is pretty involved, so I would use Google Groups/Plus or one of the other freely available services.  If you really want a Drupal distribution, I would try Open Atrium, which does bug tracking too.

Comment: Read this link
https://www.lullabot.com/blog/articles/organic-groups-drupal-7 And watch this series of videos (signup is free)
http://modulesunraveled.com/organic-groups

Answer (score 1):

As per your "*... there could be other distributions or modules that I don't know about too.*" in your question: have a look at the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module (commonly perceived as an alternative for [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)).

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable. Which also makes it integrate very well (out of the box) with commonly used modules such as [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), etc.

Some more questions you may want to look at for more details:

- [What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493), which explains the various types of roles that can be used.
- [How to bulk assign existing content to a group created with the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197489), a typical issue when adding this module to an existing site).
- [What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197618)

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".